# How do I populate a VB.NET textbox using an SQL SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, vb.net, select, textbox

How do I populate a VB.NET textbox using an SQL SELECT statement?
Any help is appreciated for a newbie like me. I am not familiar with table adapters and data tables if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be good for my learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you out...

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984467(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Hi iApple! thanks for your reply. but I am having trouble adding a TableAdapter to the wpf window. It is greyed out in the toolbox. Any idea what might be causing that, or is there a workaround?